# Ubuntu 20.04 update significantly slower when Linux/ grub package is updated

Tags: grub2, 20.04, kernel, updates

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 which has been updated to the latest packages. Along with Ubuntu, I have also installed Windows and Arch Linux parallelly on my laptop. I do regular update of Ubuntu using `apt` command. I have noticed that whenever an update contains `kernel` or `grub2` package, it takes too much to complete the update process (approx 10 min extra than without `kernel` package). I have installed the OS on SSD and details of the other system configurations are as follows:-

```
neofetch --stdout
OS: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS x86_64 
Host: X510UNR 1.0 
Kernel: 5.4.0-84-generic 
Uptime: 25 mins 
Packages: 3114 (dpkg), 17 (flatpak), 10 (snap) 
Shell: bash 5.0.17 
Resolution: 1920x1080 
DE: GNOME 
WM: Mutter 
WM Theme: Sweet-Dark 
Theme: Sweet-Dark [GTK2/3] 
Icons: candy-icons [GTK2/3] 
Terminal: gnome-terminal 
CPU: Intel i7-8550U (8) @ 4.000GHz 
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce MX150 
GPU: Intel UHD Graphics 620 
Memory: 3925MiB / 15899MiB
```

Can someone help me to improve the system update process?

Comment: *Can someone help me to improve the system update process?* No, because it's entirely normal.

Comment: IT IS NOT NORMAL. The update process of Arch Linux is much much faster with `kernel` update.

Comment: IT IS NORMAL and this isn't a shouting match. What happens with other OSes IS irrelevant. Pacman is more "efficient" than apt, most of the times. And because Arch is a rolling release updates, any and all updates, tend to be smaller and more frequent.

Comment: So, what have you done so far, and what help do you need?

Comment: I am just informing the issue I am facing. I am sure that it is not relevant to apt command. I have observed the delay even today, especially with the generation of the grub2 config file (took 9 min). That too in SSD is not accaptable. If you need more info on command output, I shall provide it.

Answer (score 1):

Your process is working well. There is nothing wrong with it at all. The only way to make this stuff faster is to try this article on overclocking ubuntu, but make sure that you have a good cooling system. I wouldn't do it though because it is not really needed... unless you actually want that. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/OverclockingCpu Another trick that speeds up installs is a faster memory device; 120 mb/seconds or more works well. If you have a spinning style hard drive, especially an older one, it will be terribly slow on any install and will probably be slower in a general sense.

Comment: I am afraid you are seriously misinformed, if you think 10 minutes to rebuild initramfs is a well working process. It has never taken so long here on an old SU2300 CPU. Also, the overclocking stuff is false.

Comment: Overcloking worked very well for me; it quadroupled the speed as in stuff loads really fast and it can do ususally long tasks in a much shorter time. But yes, I am used to 10 minutes for a simple rebuild of initramfs. Before that, It would be a half hour.

Comment: Wow, it takes 10 min after overclocking? Are you on Pentuim2 or something? Just tested, took 90 seconds on a 12 year old SU2300.

Comment: It's not a large cpu; it is a raspberry pi running ubuntu